# How to find input inside label ? - Python Selenium

Tags: python, html, selenium, xpath

I'm trying to solve this:

```
<label class='blah' style='bbb'>
    <input class='input_trello klaus black_mage' type='mail' place-holder='placeIt' name='name' id='myid'>
```

What I need is to write in the input using Selenium, everytime that I try to take it as Xpath, id or name it can't find it in HTML.

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such
element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"myid"}
```

Trying by xpath:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such 
element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="myid"]"}
```

Clan anyone give me a light in this darkness?

Comment: Do you have an implicit wait added so that the page waits to ensure the element is available, other wise an explicit wait could be a good option.  http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp

Comment: @Tbizzness, thank you! It was the answer! When I moved to another page I forgot to wait a few seconds until de HTML loads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Tbaker said, just needed to input a implicit wait on It's values:

> driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(***10***, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

to wait until the HTML loads and now it would work perfectly after getting to the new page.

Comment: Using `time.sleep()` is not the correct approach. Read @tbizzness comment again. He is talking about using implicit and/or explicit waits.